# Problema XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json

Estou lendo um arquivo JSON que está localizado em uma pasta dentro do projeto principal utilizando o JavaScript. O código dá certo em todos os navegadores, exceto o Google Chrome. Erro que aparece no chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
function readJsonFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

    function pintarMapa(estado, strokeColor, fillColor)
{
    readJsonFile("file:///Estados/"+estado+".json", function(data) {
        var dados = JSON.parse(data);
        var coord = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: dados.borders,
            strokeColor: strokeColor,// cor da borda
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: fillColor,// cor da área
            fillOpacity: 0.3
          });
        coord.setMap(map);
        console.log(dados);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não podes executar um pedido AJAX para um ficheiro local.

Se o mesmo fizer parte do projeto então poderás aceder a ele pelo caminho relativo, por exemplo, `"~/Estados/"+estado+".json"`.

Algo assim:

```
readJsonFile("~/Estados/" + estado + ".json", function (data) {
    // código
});
```

Comment: Não entendi, então o que muda no código?

Comment: Editei a resposta, espero que ajude.

Comment: O erro continua...

Comment: O projeto tem parte de servidor? Terás de ter um servidor local a correr (apache no caso de linux, ou IIS no caso de c#, por exemplo). Só com Javascript não conseguirás ler o ficheiro, é uma medida de segurança dos browsers atuais, apenas versões mais antigas do IE permitem.

Comment: Então, mesmo com todos os arquivos .json estando em minha pasta eu não conseguirei ler no google chrome? O projeto não está em um servidor.

Comment: Exatamente, a segurança do Chrome é mais apertada mas acredito que no futuro todos os browsers terão o mesmo comportamento. Uma alternativa (não testada) será alojar por exemplo na Dropbox e utilizar o link gerado para aceder ao json.

Comment: Se a minha resposta inicial ajudou a perceber o problema e como funciona quando os ficheiros estão no servidor, por favor marca como a resposta correta

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seu problema está na linha:

"readJsonFile("file:///Estados/"+estado+".json", function(data) {"

Está com 3 "/", coloque da forma correta e teste.

Comment: Não, `file://` e apenas `Estados/...` não funcionam